# airport problem, get a maximum area in a matrix in O(n^3) with DP (python)

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

"" "

- You have to build an airport and have a map H of the area where it is to be located.
- The map divides the territory into a square grid of n x n unit squares, and the corresponding height is indicated for each unit square.
- It is necessary to locate the rectangular region of maximum area (i.e. the rectangular region which consists of the largest number of squares)
- such that the height difference within the region does not exceed a given limit C.
- (i.e. the difference in height between the maximum height square of the selected region and the minimum height square of the selected region must be at most C).
- Describes an algorithm that takes the map H, and the whole C << n with complexity O (C * n ^ 3) returns a required region
- (the region to be returned can be represented by the coordinates of the first cell in the upper left and the coordinates of the last cell in the lower right of the region itself).
- For example for the 8 x 8 map

##############################

- 20 18 21 21 20 18 23 20
- 19 17 20 21 16 18 20 21
- 18 19 | 20 21 18 18 20 20 |
- 21 17 | 18 18 21 21 19 19 |
- 20 21 | 18 20 20 21 19 18 |
- 18 20 | 19 18 21 20 18 21 |
- 18 20 | 18 20 20 21 21 20 |
- 22 18 18 18 22 21 22 21

###########################

- With C = 4 a solution is the rectangle with side 5 identified by the coordinates (3, 3) and (7, 8) and highlighted in the figure.
  "" "

my code: work in O(N^6)(?)

**what would be a possible approach for DP in O(N^3)?**

```py
example
-----matrix-----
[20, 18, 21, 21, 20, 18, 23, 20]
[19, 17, 20, 21, 16, 18, 20, 21]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 18, 18, 20, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19]
[20, 21, 18, 2, 20, 21, 19, 18]
[18, 20, 19, 18, 21, 20, 18, 21]
[18, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 21, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 21, 21]
--------------------------------

SOL --> (3, 5)   (8, 8) 

____matrix__SOL__
[18, 18, 20, 20]
[21, 21, 19, 19]
[20, 21, 19, 18]
[21, 20, 18, 21]
[20, 21, 21, 20]
[21, 21, 21, 21]
________________
___________________________________________

#
-----matrix-----
[20, 18, 21, 21, 20, 18, 23, 20]
[19, 17, 20, 21, 16, 18, 20, 21]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 18, 18, 20, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19]
[20, 21, 18, 20, 20, 21, 19, 18]
[18, 20, 19, 18, 21, 20, 18, 21]
[18, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 21, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 21, 21]
--------------------------------

SOL  --> (3, 1)   (8, 8) 

________matrix___SOL_____
[18, 19, 20, 21, 18, 18, 20, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19]
[20, 21, 18, 20, 20, 21, 19, 18]
[18, 20, 19, 18, 21, 20, 18, 21]
[18, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 21, 20]
[21, 18, 18, 18, 21, 21, 21, 21]
________________________________
___________________________________________

#
-----matrix-----
[20, 18, 21, 21, 20, 18, 23, 20]
[19, 17, 20, 21, 16, 18, 20, 21]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 18, 18, 20, 20]
[21, 17, 18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19]
[20, 21, 18, 20, 20, 21, 19, 18]
[18, 20, 19, 18, 21, 20, 18, 21]
[18, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 21, 20]
[22, 18, 18, 18, 22, 21, 22, 21]
--------------------------------

SOLUZIONE  --> (3, 3)   (7, 8) 

______matrix_SOL_____
[20, 21, 18, 18, 20, 20]
[18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19]
[18, 20, 20, 21, 19, 18]
[19, 18, 21, 20, 18, 21]
[18, 20, 20, 21, 21, 20]
________________________
___________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
data = [[20,18,21,21,20,18,23,20],[19,17,20,21,16,18,20,21],[18,19,20,21,18,18,20,20],[21,17,18,18,21,21,19,19],[20,21,18,20,20,21,19,18],[18,20,19,18,21,20,18,21],[18,20,18,20,20,21,21,20],[22,18,18,18,22,21,22,21]]
C=4
max_area = -10**7
for k in range(8,1,-1):
    max_val = -10**7
    min_val = 10**7
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(k):
            if(data[i][j]>max_val):
                max_val = data[i][j]
            if(data[i][j]<min_val):
                min_val = data[i][j]
    if(max_val-min_val<=C):
        temp_area = (i+1)*(j+1)
        if(temp_area>max_area):
            print("Top Left:", (i,j))
            print("Bottom Right:", (i+k,j+k))
            break
```

Comment: this work only for the first case and isn't a dynamic programming, thanks anyway –

Comment: @DanielFerro Ofcourse, it is not dynamic, did you care to mention in question what is the range of inputs you will be considering??? And what are different types of test cases??